# Can you return the color of a rectangle object in java?

Tags: java, javafx, colors, shapes

For example, I create a rectangle object and set its fill to black. Would I be able to check the fill color of the rectangle to determine if its white or black? Something like:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0);

if (r.getFill == 'BLACK') {
    r.setFill(Color.'PURPLE');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`getFill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#getFill--) method returns a [`Paint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Paint.html) object. Therefore, you should use `equals` for comparison:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(1.0, 1.0, Color.WHITE);

if (r.getFill().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
    System.out.println("That's a white rectangle.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the `Rectangle` that is a subclass of `javafx.scene.shape.Shape`, then yes, there is a method named `getFill` that returns a `Paint` ([Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#getFill--))