# Is it possible to compare an index in an array to a color?

Tags: java, arrays, colors, rectangles

I'm trying to code a board game and have created the board with for loops. As it stands now I can click a rectangle and am able to change its color. Now I want to have it where if I click a rectangle that is a certain color to change it to a specific color. For example iff it's blue then make it grey. However I get the error `Unlikely argument type for equals(): Color seems to be unrelated to Rectangle` and my squares turn black instead. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
public void game (MouseEvent eventGame) {
    for(Rectangle r: rectangles) {
        if (r.equals(Color.BLUE)) {
            r.setOnMouseClicked(event->{
                r.setFill(Color.GREY);
            });
        } else { r.setOnMouseClicked(event->{
                r.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            });}
    }
}
```

I should also mention when creating the Array I do this: `r.setFill(Color.BLUE);`.

Comment: compare rgb codes.

Comment: You are not comparing "an index to a color", which already makes no sense, but a Rectangle and a Color. That's like comparing a banana and    mickey mouse. You probably wants to get the rectangle filling color.

Comment: Why does that method take an `eventGame` parameter and go through all the `Rectangles` setting each their own `onMouseClicked` handler? Seems really convoluted and unnecessary. What class is `Rectangle`? Is it JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling

> r.equals(Color.BLUE)

you are trying to compare a rectangle instance with a Color type. Looking at the API of Rectangle, its equals-method is described as follows:

> Checks whether two rectangles are equal. 
>   The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Rectangle object that has the same upper-left corner, width, and height as this Rectangle.

Instead you need to compare the actual Color of the rectangle by calling

> r.getFill().equals(Color.WHITE)

(see Post [Can you return the color of a rectangle object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196753/can-you-return-the-color-of-a-rectangle-object-in-java))

Hope, I could help you.